# How to solve this syntax error, "identifier" expected but "ordinal const" found?

Tags: pascal, freepascal, pascalscript

> (14,22) Error: Illegal qualifier
> (14,22) Fatal: Syntax error, "identifier" expected but "ordinal const" found

```
PROGRAM menentukan_bonus_karyawan;
    uses crt;
var    
    nama, golongan: string;
    lama_kerja : integer;
    bonus : real;
begin
    clrscr;
    write('Masukkan nama anda : '); readln(nama);
    write('Golongan karyawan (staf/ non-staf) : '); readln(golongan);
    write('Lama kerja : '); readln(lama_kerja);
    case (golongan) of 
        'staf'      : if lama_kerja >= 10 then
                        bonus := 1.000.000     <--- error line
                      else 
                        bonus := 700.000;
        'non-staf'  : if lama_kerja >= 10 then
                        bonus := 500.000
                      else
                        bonus := 350.000;
    end;
    writeln('Saudara ', nama, ' dengan golongan karyawan ', golongan, ' mendapatkan bonus sebesar Rp. ', bonus);
    readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the value of `1.000.000` is invalid. If you meant one million, then you should use `1000000`. If you wanted one thousand, then you could use `1000.000`.

Comment: Considering that `bonus` is of data type `real` and the values in the remaining source code, @tazuu probably meant to write `1000.000`. FYI, [FPC will support underscore as digit separator](https://wiki.freepascal.org/Special:PermaLink/154274#Support_for_Digit_Separator), so something like `1_000.000` could be legal.

Comment: The underscore bit s not in release versions yet.